# Creating a map of lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, lambda

How can I describe a map of lambda? I want to have a map of lambda which will be called on event (just as a simple callback). The lambda type is constant.

Comment: Do you mean a `std::map` of them, or something else?

Comment: Yep, I mean that `std::map` should contain lambda functions.

Comment: I doubt that lambda _type_ is actually a "constant". In this case all lamdas would belong to the same lambda class and therefore do the same thing :). Perhaps, lambda signatures are the same?

Comment: @user396672: Actually, the C++ standard precies that each lambda has a unique type of its own. However, they can be safely wrapped into `std::function< XXX >` with the appropriate signature and even (for those without captures) degenerate into simple pointer to functions.

Comment: Isn't there a way with mpl? As the lambdas are known at compile time anyway? What is the key and value of the map?

Comment: @balki: What does mpl means? Yes I know that lambdas are in compilation level. The map should be like this something like this std::map<int,function<void(int)> >.

Comment: mpl means meta programming library. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html It is basically based on templates.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `<functional>` header and the `std::function` template class. This allows you to specify function objects with a fixed method signature.

```
std::map< unsigned int, std::function<int(int,int)> > callbackMap;
```

Assuming that you index the callbacks using an `unsigned int`, the above map stores functions that take in two `int` and return an `int`.